# How to change index page for one IP address?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've installed another theme on my site and I need to improve it. How can I change the index file only for my IP address?

My current htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need to change the index file to `index.WP.php` for the IP address `203.0.113.111`. Is it possible?

Comment: Just create a dev copy of your site on a different URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just repeat the front controller part and include a condition for your IP address. For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### ALTERNATIVE FRONT CONTROLLER FOR SPECIFIC IP ADDRESS
RewriteRule ^index\.WP\.php$ - [L]

# Special case for document root to override DirectoryIndex
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =203.0.113.111
RewriteRule ^$ /index.WP.php [L]

# Route all other requests for specific IP address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =203.0.113.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.WP.php [L]

### DEFAULT FRONT CONTROLLER FOR ALL OTHER USERS
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will only route the user with IP address `203.0.113.111` to `index.WP.php`. All other visitors get passed through to the default front controller. This still allows any user to *directly* request `index.WP.php` if they want to (if they know it exists).

<s>**UPDATE:** Note that I've changed the `RewriteRule` *pattern* on the first *front controller* rule block from `.` to `^` - this allows it to match the document root, ie. `http://www.example.com/`, so it can override the default `DirectoryIndex`.</s>

**UPDATE:** For the "alternative" front controller (via the specific IP address), a special case is required for the document root in order to override the `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.php`). (The previous update wouldn't have been enough since the document root is obviously a directory, so the *preceding condition* (`!-d`) still fails.)

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) http;//www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Note that you have an erroneous semicolon (`;`) after the *scheme* on your canonical non-www to www redirect.

Comment: Yes it is working correctly, but not work only for main page. How can I change main page of my site too.

Comment: Ah yes, you'll need to change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ so that it matches _anything_, rather than _something_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, the previous update was not enough. The directive would have still failed to rewrite the document root since the preceding condition that ensures it's not a directory would have still failed. I think a special case is required for the document root in order to override the `DirectoryIndex`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code in your `index.php` file. And change `203.0.113.111` to your public / static IP and change Location URL. It will resolve your concern

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='203.0.113.111' ||  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']=='203.0.113.111')
{
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/yourindex.php");
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php");
}
```

Comment: No need to redirect to `index.php`, since you are already there. However, you can (and should) avoid an external redirect here.